# Why can't Kleopatra (gpg4win) import my freshly-created key from another PC?

Tags: gnupg

I **just created** two new [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) **keys** on my linux box and then **tried to import** the public keys on my Windows 7 machine running [gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/index.html) 2.1.0 with Kleopatra. However, I always get the message

```
Insgesamt bearbeitet:  2
Importiert:   0
Zertifikate ohne Benutzerkennungen:   2
```

or in English

```
Processed: 2
Imported: 0
Certificates without user IDs: 2
```

i.e. **nothing is being imported**.

**What is the problem with these keys??** I just created them myself, minutes ago, and brought them over from the Linux machine using an USB stick. **They both do have a user ID!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out more about the actual problem, **don't trust Kleopatra's error message**.

Running gpg2.exe from the command line, I got this:

```
gpg: key C0D3AFD2 was created 1810 seconds in the future (time warp or clock problem)
[...]
gpg: key C0D3AFD2: no valid user IDs
gpg: this may be caused by a missing self-signature
[...]
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 2
```

**So the signatures are being refused because their time/date is wrong!**

Sure enough, the clock on the Linux machine which created the keys was set two hours into the future...